# CPU fan is louder while running Windows 10 vs other OS

Tags: linux, windows-10, fan, cpu-cooler

I've noticed that while running Windows 10, the CPU fan makes more sound than when running another system. I can barely hear it spinning while running Kali or Debian.

What could be the cause? Perhaps it's just me, or booting to Windows 10 the causes the fan to start spinning faster, making more noise.

Comment: that would indicate that under windows 10, your CPU is running hotter, and the fan needs to spin up to keep it cool. I'd start by using a tool like speedfan/coretemp/cpu-z/speccy to read the CPU temp. remember, your fan is only making noise because its working harder, so the issue (if there is one) is not the volume, but how hot the CPU is.

Comment: win10 includes more app crap that runs in background and this makes the CPU hotter so the cpu cooler has to do more work. On my Win10 test the CPU was 10°C hotter compared to Win8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because Windows 10 is more resource intensive, which causes the CPU to heat up. When the CPU heats up, it has to be cooled. The fan cools it, so that is why you hear the fan. You can see the resources currently being used by opening Task Manager on Windows, or System Monitor in Kali/Debian.